# debug openresty with zerobrane

Tags: lua, openresty, zerobrane

I've followed this tutorial to setting up [Zerobrane IDE](https://studio.zerobrane.com/) for debugging [openresty](https://openresty.org/en/):
http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio.

I installed openresty 1.19.3.1 from a brew formula, and lua scripts are working.

Double checked everything with zerobrane, the error i got:

```
Debugger server started at vgh.local:8172.
Can't start debugging for '/usr/local/Cellar/openresty/1.19.3.1_1/nginx/lua/content.lua'. Compilation error:
Debugger connection closed
Debugging session completed (traced 0 instructions).
Refused a request to start a new debugging session as there is one in progress already.
```

What should i check?
This is the conf i have on macos, but i got the same error on a linux (ubuntu 20.10):

```
lua_package_path '/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?/?.lua;/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?.lua;;';
lua_package_cpath '/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/clibs/?.dylib;;';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of ZeroBrane Studio you are using, but you'll need to use the latest one from the master branch in the [repository](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio), as there have been several [openresty-related fixes applied to the debugger](https://github.com/pkulchenko/MobDebug/issues/51) and [merged recently](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/805a05a421d3a25e770c48b8772d0da4ed506313) .

Comment: ZeroBrane Studio (1.90; MobDebug 0.706) from https://download.zerobrane.com/ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.90-macos.dmg

ok! thanks, i will download it from the gh repo